# Cordova: Could not load config.xml on Windows platform

Tags: cordova, cordova-win10

I'm having hard times with Cordova. Everything was ok, until yesterday. I've built Windows package of my application but noticed that application has contents of an old version. Removed platform, added once again... and here you go. Now I can't run it anymore on Windows. Every time I want to debug it in VS2015 I'm getting error: [Windows][cordova.js][readConfig] Could not XHR config.xml: {}. But config.xml is there! What should I check? There is no such problem with Android platform. It compiles normally.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. It seems that easiest solution was the right one. I've had to delete windows platform from Cordova and create it again. It's working now, duh.

Edit: I ran cordova plugin save and cordova platform save too. Not sure what helped.